# What OS for Eee PC?

Tags: windows-7, linux, netbook

I've just bought new Eee PC 1005 (with Atom N450, 250GB and 2GB memory) without any pre-installed system. Now I'd like to install windows and linux distribution on in. What should I choose ? I am a programmer and web designer, so I need Java IDE , Python interpreters, and Photoshop (on windows). Will Win 7 Pro 32bit work ?Or should I choose Windows XP ? And what about linux distro ? Ubuntu, Eeebuntu, Ubuntu netbook edition ?

btw is it true that linux's grub overrides mbr so that hardware system restore doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use Ubuntu Netbook Remix on my Asus eeePC 1005PE. It works out of the box, wireless, bluetooth, webcam all fine. There is a slight problem with the built-in microphone but there's a workaround.
I've installed Eclipse (but haven't tested fully) which is a Java (and the rest...) IDE. You can install Gimp (as Photoshop replacement).

Yes, grub overwrites the mbr, but that's not what controls the hardware system restore (as far as I know - don't blame me if you lose it).
As I understand it, the hardware system restore lives in a separate partition near the end of the disk (along with Asus' own operating system Express Gate in an even smaller partition). When I installed Ubuntu, I was careful to leave those partitions alone, although it did take a bit of guesswork to find out which they were. If you leave them alone, Grub will auto-detect the system restore partition (mine calls it Windows Vista (Loader) - even though it came with Windows 7 pre-installed) and give you the option to boot up into "windows" but if you do this, you lose your Ubuntu installation because it restores the system back to factory state.

On mine, I left the end two partitions, the 11Gb FAT (I'm guessing system restore??), and the 17MB EFI, FAT-12/16/32, (I'm guessing Asus Express Gate).

WARNING: This is mostly guesswork, I haven't tested the system restore as I do not want to lose my Ubuntu installation. I'm not even sure if it will work when I try it. Make sure you do your research before doing anything potentially irreversible.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Netbook Remix (10.04) on an Asus EeePC 901, and I'm very happy with it. It's actually a dual boot set up, where Windows XP is the other OS - but I only use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't go with Windows XP SP2. Support for XP SP2 [ends on July 13, 2010](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/end-support-windows-xp-sp2-windows-vista-without-service-packs?os=xp), 42 days from now. All support for Windows XP is scheduled to end April 8, 2014.

Comment: That says support for "XP with SP2" ends - so SP3 is still supported, no?

Comment: Also, who cares?  I've never needed "support" for XP from Micrsoft.

Comment: ashh, be careful out there! It's not just phone and email support. It's also support as in "providing patches for security vulnerabilities".